# Как найти элемент по имени класса в selenium?

Tags: java, css, selenium

Есть список `HTML` элементов `a`:

```
<a href="#" class="row_move _move_wrap _my_move" onmouseover="Wall.movesShow(this, '17451649_1739')" onclick="return Wall.moveIt(this, '17451649_1739', '19a5fe69eba3274571', event);">
      <i class="post_move_icon _icon"></i>
      <span class="post_move_link _link">move</span>
      <span class="post_move_count _count">6</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="row_move _move_wrap" onmouseover="Wall.movesShow(this, '17451649_1739')" onclick="return Wall.moveIt(this, '17451649_1739', '19a5fe69eba3274571', event);">
      <i class="post_move_icon _icon"></i>
      <span class="post_move_link _link">move</span>
      <span class="post_move_count _count">6</span>
</a>
```

До первого обращения к элементу он имеет набор классов `row_move _move_wrap` (как во втором `<а>`), а после одного обращения к ним добавляется еще один (как в первом `<а>`) `row_move _move_wrap _my_move`.

Мне нужно проходить по ним по очередно, так что бы ориентироваться по принципу: раз `_my_move` уже есть, значит там уже были ищем следующий.
Сейчас я просто ищу по селектору:

```
By.cssSelector("._move_wrap")
```

А как мне отбросить в выборке те в которых уже есть `_my_move`? Можно ли выставить условие в селекторе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через xpath можно задать условие:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "_move_wrap") and not(contains(@class, "_my_move"))]'))
```

Вернет все элементы `a`, у которых есть класс `_move_wrap` и нет класса `_my_move`

Comment: @Pavel, всегда забываю эту скобочку в конце) спасибо